# Selecting first and next cell in filtered criteria range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to select next cell in Filtered range using VBA

For example,
Column A having set of values and column B having set of values,
I have to filter column B and criteria is Sunday for eg.,

for Sunday I want to re-write as Noted down.

I tried this code also
With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
Range("B" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Select

End with

I am getting error of Application defined or object defined error.

We cant even simply move to next cell in filtered range?
Any easy way is there to move to first and next cell in filtered criteria?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVTsA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHrVS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... It will update each cell for filtered data in c column...

```
Sub code()

Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$C$10")
Rng.Columns(3).ClearContents
Rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Sunday"

For Each cell In Rng.Columns(3).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    cell.Value = "Noted Down"
Next cell
Selection.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to update directly in B column instead of Sunday, wherever I find I have to update Noted down using Filter criteria range and really thanks for commenting for the question it really helps.

Comment: Yes @Itzmeram, its possible... just have to edit the column number... Rng.Columns(3) -> Rng.Columns(2) ... so now the column B will get updated... Drop a like & accept the best answer that works for your problem statement... To grow & motivate community... Happy Coding :)